# Bioenergetics book

Tags: biophysics, bioenergetics

I already [asked this question on the physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502616/bioenergetics-book-biophysics?noredirect=1#comment1132409_502616) but redirected here:

In the field of biophysics, it seems there is a subfield called "bioenergetics" about the processes of generating energy by biology. I am looking for a book to be introduced to the physics aspects of bioenergetics. I checked up on Springer and there seem to be quite some books on the topic, but the problem is that I fear that they would require heavy biology basics.

Comment: Whether you are talking about generating heat energy, kinetic energy, or releasing chemical energy, you'll certainly need an understanding of the underlying molecular biology and/or biochemistry. It depends on what you mean by "heavy biology basics". For instance, understanding oxidative phosphorylation would require you to understand that mitochondria have a double membrane and are equipped with an electron transporting machinery within one of the membranes. That certainly *is* biology.

Comment: @SPr Understood, but is there a book that is "self-contained" in some way that the biology basics like "mitochondria" are explained?

Comment: Ok so the vital force seems to be oriented towards biochemistry, right? And what is the purpose on Harold on the Peter Michell Nobel prize? I didn't understand the purpose of it in the question. Do you, by any chance, have the list of chapters of The Vital Force?

Comment: Sounds a bit too advanced, but a good reference nonetheless :)